# Symbolising 2.5D polyline based on slope of each segment using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, 3d, qgis-3

I have a 2.5D polyline (each vertex has an elevation value) of a hiking route. I would like to change the line width depending on the slope of each segment in order to visualise how difficult each section of the route would be.

If necessary the segments could be split into individual features in a layer which could have a graduated symbology based on a calculated slope but ideally the route would remain intact as a single line.

Comment: Have a look at the arrow symbol type. You can set a different width at the start and end of each arrow using data-defined settings.